# How to await on a promise that is returned in an array without destructuring first?

Tags: javascript

If I have something like,

```
const apiCall = async (url) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    return [url, data];
  } catch ({ response: { data } }) {
    console.log('Error', data);
  }
}
```

Say I want to call and access the data from the promise. I'd have to do something like,

```
const [, call] = await validate('/api/root');
const data = await call;
```

Is there a way to do this in a one liner, without having to access the call, something like,

`await (await validate('/api/root'))`?

Comment: How is `data` a promise here? And why does the caller have to `await` it, why can't it be resolved inside `apiCall` (`validate`?)

Comment: Ahh, the dangers of getting so used to destructuring that you forget how to access properties and arrays normally :P

Comment: @FelixKling Old code that is not to be refactored, only worked with.

Comment: @Klaycon Tell me about it lol

Comment: Are `apiCall` in the first code block and `validate` in the second are the same function? You might want to edit the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

This is an equivalent one-liner:

```
const data = await (await validate('/api/root'))[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an awaited function inside an argument. So something like

```js
const result = await apiCall(
  await validate(),
  url
)
```

Then you could handle the validation inside `apiCall`.

Or you could just add the validate function as a callback inside apiCall if it's dependent on the result of apiCall.